# Duplicate columns when assigning alisas in conjunction with select *

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Assigning an alias to columns in conjuction with using the select all synatx duplicates the columns in the query.

For example,

```
select table.a AS 'This is a', * from table
```

Gives the below result

| This is a | a |
| --- | --- |
| test_1 | 1 |
| test_2 | 2 |

As you can see above, this duplicates the column. In my this case, I am required to use the * syntax to select all columns as new columns are added often.

Comment: Hi - you haven't actually asked a question. Also, it’s unclear to me what the issue is - you mention duplicated columns but in the result you’ve provided there don’t seem to be any duplicated columns

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

If you have more columns in the table then this way would be bit easy to exclude a column that you dont want.
You can drop your columns that you dont want to include in your table.

```
create table new_table as
select table.a AS 'This is a', * from table;

alter table new_table drop column new_table.a;

select * from new_table;
```